# ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to concatenate 2 dataframes with hierarchical indexes on axis=1, each one for a different year composed of four quarters (03, 06, 09, 12). Just to give you an idea, the following is for 2018:

```
        201803                     | 201806                     | 201809 | 201812
        Open     Close     Adjust  | Open     Close     Adjust  | ...    | ...                  
AAPL    123.00   124.00    124.00  | 125.00   126.00    126.00  | ...    | ...
```

These dataframes have then a hierarchical index on 2 levels. When I try to concatenate 2018 and 2019 it doesn't work, showing the error in the title. This looks like duplicated indexes (non-unique) but this is not the case: if I print the first-level indexes I see [201803, 201806, 201809, 201812] for 2018 and [201903, 201906, 201909, 201912] for 2019.
If I use ignore_index=True it works but then the hierarchical index is lost. To concatenate I use the following code (my_dict is a dictionary of dataframes):

```
df_full_years = pd.concat([my_dict["2018"], my_dict["2019"]], axis=1)
```

Moreover, previously I have created the dataframes concatenating the quarters for each year and it has worked. Any idea why it doesn't work even if the indexes are unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: after counting the indexes with the code:

```
df.columns.value_counts()
```

I've discovered that the issue is in the index level 1, not in the index level 0. The level 1 has more than 100 items and one is duplicated in the json file I was working on.
I have just dropped the duplicated indexes and now it works properly.